# what method is the correct way of implemeting dice loss ? sigmoid or softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have a binary semantic segmentation problem and there is 2 method in my mind.

Method 1:
Unet output one class with sigmoid activation, then I use the dice loss to calculate the loss

Method 2:
The ground truth is concatenated to it is inverse, thus having 2 classes. The output of Unet is 2 classes and applying softmax activation to them. The dice loss is then used to calculate the loss.

Which is correct?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207049/neural-network-for-binary-classification-use-1-or-2-output-neurons). If you have a 2 class problem, output only 1 channel, use a sigmoid function (outputs values between 0 and 1). Then you can calculate your dice loss with output (continuous values) and target(single channel one-hot-encoded, discrete values). If your network outputs 2 channels use a softmax function and calculate your loss with your output (continous values) and target (2 channel one-hot-encoded). The former is preferred, as you will have less parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Method 2 is correct, since softmax is used for multi-class problems.